# Count number of characters in between 2 different substrings - Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following script (written by a colleague) which searches input text (DNA-sequence) for a specific sub-string and essentially outputs a count of the number of letters in between each occurrence of this sub-string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#read file in from input line
$infile = $ARGV[0];
open(TXT, "<$infile");

#open output stream
$outfile = $ARGV[1];
open(OUT, ">$outfile");

#initialize a blank string for the DNA sequence
$DNA = &read_fasta();

$len = length($DNA);
print "\n DNA Length is: $len \n";

#restriction enzyme match pattern
$pattern = "AGCT";

$match = 0;

while($DNA =~ /$pattern/gi)
{
    $match++;
}

print "\n Total DNA matches to AGCT are: $match \n";

# split the DNA sequence into an array of fragments
@cutarr = split(/$pattern/i, $DNA);

#write the fragments out to a file
foreach $str(@cutarr)
{
    $len = length($str);
    print OUT "$len \n";
}


# Subfunction to read in a fasta file
sub read_fasta
{
    $sequence = "";

    while(<TXT>)
    {
        $line = $_;

        #remove newline characters
        chomp($line);

         # discard fasta header line
        if($line =~ /^>/){ next }

        # append the line to the DNA sequence
        else { $sequence .= $line }
    }
    return($sequence);
}

print "DNA is: \n $sequence \n";
```

I was wondering if anybody could help me to include a second search pattern such that the script outputs the number of characters between any hit of the 2 searches i.e. if $pattern1= AGCT and $pattern2 = GATC and the input sequence is:

GGGGCC-AGCT-GAGAGACC-GATC-GAGAGAGAG-AGCT-

I've put -'s just to show where the search hits are.

The output will consist of:

```
6
8
9
```

Thank you!

- Kayleigh

Comment: Are the patterns always alternating? Like `AGCTGGGAGCT` is not allowed since two consequtive AGCT are following each other..? And does the string always start with AGCT pattern, or could it also start with GATC pattern?

Comment: The patterns are not always alternating and can appear in any order and it can start with either. There can also be situations where the pattern may be adjacent i.e. AGCTAGCT.

Comment: Ok I see.. then for the string: `AGCTGGAGCTGGGATC`, would the output be: `8` ( then number of characters between `AGCT` and `GATC`) or `2` and `2` (also counting number of characters between `AGTC` and `AGTC`)?

Comment: The output for that would be 2 and 2. I should also mention that it's not only between the hits but leading up to the first one too. For example: GGAGCTGGAGCTGGGATC would be 2,2,2 even though there was no proceeding hit for the initial GG.

Comment: Ok, see my answer below. Does that work as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following script:

```
use v5.12;
use autodie;

open(my $in, "<", shift);

open(my $out, ">", shift);

my $DNA = read_fasta($in);

print "DNA is: \n $$DNA \n";
my $len = length($$DNA);
print "\n DNA Length is: $len \n";

my @pats=qw( AGCT GATC );

for (@pats) {
    my $m = () = $$DNA =~ /$_/gi;
    print "\n Total DNA matches to $_ are: $m \n";
}

my $pat=join("|",@pats);

my @cutarr = split(/$pat/, $$DNA);

#write the fragments out to a file
for (@cutarr) {
    my $len = length($_);
    print $out "$len \n";
}
close($out);
close($in);


# Subfunction to read in a fasta file
sub read_fasta {
    my ($in) = @_;
    my $sequence = "";

    while(<$in>) {
        my $line = $_;

        #remove newline characters
        chomp($line);

         # discard fasta header line
        if($line =~ /^>/){ next }

        # append the line to the DNA sequence
        else { $sequence .= $line }
    }
    return(\$sequence);
}
```